# how to change a TR background color based on value of a column

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table that is populated from a query using PDO. One of the columns (FLAG_CLOSED) I return from the query is what drives the color change. What I need to do, is change the background color of a  based on the value of the column. The value can be 'Y','N', or empty. Below is a snippet of the table (I left out the header row) and what I've tried so far. I didn't think this would work but it's all I could think of at the moment. I'm not opposed to Javascript I just couldn't think of how to manipulate the dom in a way to accomplish what I need. any help is appreciated! thanks in advance.

```
<tbody>
   <tr data-flag=<?php $sub_data['FLAG_CLOSED']?>> //also tried putting quotes around the php
     <td><?php echo ($sub_data['SEQ'])?></td>
     <td><?php echo ($sub_data['PART'])?></td>
     <td><?php echo ($sub_data['LMO'])?></td>
     <td><?php echo ($sub_data['UM'])?></td>
     <td><?php echo ($sub_data['HOURS_ESTIMATED'])?></td>
     <td><?php echo ($sub_data['HOURS_ACTUAL'])?></td>
     <td><?php echo ($sub_data['DATE_START'])?></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

CSS:

```
tr [data-flag="Y"]{
  background-color: green;
}

tr [data-flag="N"]{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Table:
[Example table with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEtBT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set an ID on the TR and then targeted the ID in CSS:
HTML:

```
<tr id="<?php echo $sub_data['FLAG_CLOSED'];?>"> // evals to Y, N, or empty
```

CSS:

```
#Y{background-color: green;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to have the quotes around the php in the tr tag

Change the CSS to:

```
tr[data-flag="Y"]{
  background-color: green;
}

tr[data-flag="N"]{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Notice there isn't a space between the tag and data selector

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply. unfortunately that didn't work. the php resolves in the tr tag. but the CS just isn't applying. I tried setting an ID on the TR tag as well and changing the color in CSS based off ID but the CSS still isn't applying.

Comment: and now it is working. I'll post my answer

Answer (score 0):

As far as the code you have posted, the issue is one of rendering, and not one of CSS.

You have two typos in what you have posted.

First, in your HTML, you need to wrap your `<tbody>` in a `<table>` tag (which I assume you are doing, but didn't include here for reasons of clarity, which is fine.) Secondly, the space between your selectors in your CSS in your initial question was incorrect.

CSS cares about whitespace, and the selector comes as a modifier to your initial lookup.

```
tr[data-flag="Y"] {
  background-color: green;
}

tr[data-flag="N"] td {
  background-color: red;
}
```

This will work because the filter (the part in the brackets) from the `tr` knows to apply to your `tr` element. Otherwise writing it like `tr []` will remove that logic. You were on the right track initially, but had a dastardly whitespace issue. Your ID method (as posted in your response) will not work as well with having multiple rows selected `yes` or `no`, since IDs are supposed to be unique.

Comment: sorry this is a late response. But i see what you mean with the ID's not being unique. however, I tried both your suggestions above and it's not applying the color to the rows.